# Changing Nexus' default conf directory

Tags: tomcat, nexus

I've recently taken over an environment running Sonatype Nexus.  A few weeks in, we had a power failure which resulted in the NAS box which contains the Nexus data being offline for a few hours for a disk rebuild.  Since Nexus has been back online, our standard repositories and users have been missing due to Nexus resetting to defaults (it's a known bug/feature according to the Nexus JIRA).

However, I haven't yet found a way to point Nexus back towards "our" conf directory.  I've set $NEXUS_HOME to /share/nexus (where /conf resides) and also $NEXUS_WORK.  However, restarting Tomcat still sees Nexus pick up the data that it's been using since the power loss.

Can anyone help point me to what I need to set to get Nexus to pick up the correct conf directory?

Nexus 2.7, CentOS Linux.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sonatype-work/nexus/conf/nexus.xml file got corrupted.  Newer versions of Nexus have protection against this, but yours (2.7) doesn't.  Do you have a backup of this file, or better yet, the entire conf directory?  If so, restore it, that will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm still not sure what happened to this, but we ended up having to set the overrides for each and every repository to point them manually to the NAS again.  We'll be moving this server soon anyway so didn't go to the effort of rebuilding it.  However, we did have to rsync the local disk to the NAS box to try to get everything back in sync without data loss.